# Char ** keeps getting overwritten when recursivley adding to it

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, heap-memory, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have code that is supposed to take files in a directory, puts them into a string array, and prints the contents. Currently in my Functions.c file, it successfully writes to the correct array index, but is overwritten when I write to the next array Index. Any help is appreciated.

Main.c

```
#include "Headers.h"


    void main(){
        listFiles("C:/Users/me/Documents/testDoc");
        //printf("%s",fileArray[0]);
        printf("End");
        return;
    }
```

Functions.c

```
#include "Headers.h"


void listFiles(const char *foldername){
    struct dirent *dp; //creates object of struct dirent
    DIR *dir=opendir(foldername); //creates object of directory
    char **fileArray=(char **)calloc(1,sizeof(char *));
    if (!dir) //checks to see if directory exsists
        return;
    int numloops=1;
    while ((dp = readdir(dir)) != NULL)//recursivley goes through list
    {
        printf("%d\n",numloops);
        if(numloops==1){
            fileArray[0]=dp->d_name; //maps first file to position zero
            printf("%s test\n",fileArray[0]);
        }
        else{
            fileArray=realloc(fileArray,numloops*sizeof(char *));
            fileArray[numloops-1]=dp->d_name; //maps next file in order to position -1 to make enough memory since array starts at 0
            printf("%s test\n",fileArray[numloops-1]);
        }

        numloops++;
        printf("%s original\n", dp->d_name);//maps d_name recursivley
    }
    // Close directory stream
    printf("Value at index 2 %s\n",fileArray[2]);
    printf("Value at index 3 %s\n",fileArray[3]);
    closedir(dir);
    return;
}
```

Headers.h

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dirent.h>
void listFiles(const char *foldername);
```

Output

```
1
. test
. original
2
.. test
.. original
3
Doc 1.txt test
Doc 1.txt original
4
Doc 2.txt test
Doc 2.txt original
5
Doc 3.txt test
Doc 3.txt original
Value at index 2 Doc 3.txt
Value at index 3 Doc 3.txt
End
```

Expected output

```
1
. test
. original
2
.. test
.. original
3
Doc 1.txt test
Doc 1.txt original
4
Doc 2.txt test
Doc 2.txt original
5
Doc 3.txt test
Doc 3.txt original
Value at index 2 Doc 1.txt
Value at index 3 Doc 2.txt
End
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

From [this `readdir` reference](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/readdir.html):

> The returned pointer, and pointers within the structure, might be invalidated or the structure or the storage areas might be overwritten by a subsequent call to `readdir()` on the same directory stream.

What that sentence is saying is that `readdir` could return a pointer to the same structure over and over again, and that means that the `d_name` member would be the same each and every time.

So when you do

```
fileArray[numloops-1]=dp->d_name;
```

you make all elements in the array point to the exact same memory.

The solution is to *duplicate* the string `d_name`, like for example

```
fileArray[numloops-1]=strdup(dp->d_name);
```

Of course, once you're done you need to `free` each and every string in the array.